# Java Loops are kicking my butt

Tags: java, loops, computer-science

Hi i am having trouble with loops. I am confused on how to set up a way to get the

- the lowest score
- the highest score
- the average of the scores

and If no scores were entered, display the message that “No test grade scores were entered”.

i also had to sent up a counter which i did, and i also had to validate if the score was from 0 to 100 which i did i just don't know what to do next

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class loops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int average = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int score;



        System.out.print("Please enter first score:");
        score = keyboard.nextInt();




        while (score!=-1){

       while ((score>=0)&&(score<=100)){

            System.out.println("the score is between 0 to 100 ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the next test score:");
            score = keyboard.nextInt();
             count = count + 1;

        }


        }


        average = (score/count);
        System.out.println("The average is " +average);
        System.out.println("The number of test scores enter was:"+count);


    }

}
```

Comment: Get the data, then stream them to go for `Math::max`, `Math::min`, and the average reduction function.

Comment: How would i set up the list of scores? that is the part that is confusing me. When i enter the scores in myself and end the loop it just comes up as -1 and nothing else.

Comment: This should honestly take some 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See explanations in comments:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops { //use java naming convention

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int  count = 0,  score = 0, min = 0, max = 0, sum =0;
        float average = 0;//the average might not be int

        System.out.print("Please enter first score:");
        score = keyboard.nextInt();

        //add it to sum
        sum = score;
        //keep first number as min and max
        min = score;  max = score;

        count++;//increment counter

        //this is not needed, score of -1 will stop the next loop any way
        //while (score!=-1){

        while (true){

            System.out.println("the score is between 0 to 100 ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the next test score, or -1 to quit:");
            score = keyboard.nextInt();

            if((score < 0) ||(score > 100)) {
                break;
            }
            count++;//increment counter

            //you need to sum all entered numbers
            sum += score;

            //check if entered number is min
            if(score < min) {
                min = score ;
            }

            //check if entered number is max
            if(score >  max) {
                max = score ;
            }
        }

        if(count >0 ) {
            average = ((float)sum/count);
            System.out.println("The average is " +average );
            System.out.println("The min is " +min);
            System.out.println("The max is " +max);
            System.out.println("The number of test scores enter was:"+count);
        }else {
            System.err.println("No numbers entered");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications as needed.

Comment: Great work.  Are you going to sit his exam for him too?

Comment: @StephenC :  A. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice B. the fact that you think that hints are best, does not make it true for everybody. I learn best from well explained examples. C.Keep up the good work helping others

Comment: What did I say that was un-nice?  I am just pointing out the obvious flaw in your approach.

Comment: I honestly just wanted help it to be pointed into the right direction. I was just really confused on how it was done. Thank you for going step by step it did make it clear to me but it still gave me everything ugh.

Comment: But thank you for everyones help i just think looping is a pain in the butt to learn i just need to work on it more i guess.

Comment: @RyRy - But here's the 64,000 dollar question.  Did you actually learn how to write a loop your self from reading this code?  Will you be able to do this for yourself next time?   If you seriously think that looping in "a pain in the butt", I think the answer has to be ... No.

Comment: I have another looping assignment coming up i will try my best just to use my teacher and my book for it.

Comment: @ Stephen i did understand how he got most of it. I just forgot about the break and that you can just keep going with if statements. I am sorry that it was just given to me i am  new to all of this it is a bit hard. Its like learning a new language.

Comment: But i do need to do more on my own and i have this is like assignment ten for us and this is the only one that truly stumped me.

Comment: @RyRy - Understanding is one thing, being able to do it yourself is a different thing.

Comment: That is true but i am going to work on this more myself over this weekend so i can get it more.

Comment: I am also going to ask my teacher for more problems for me to do just to get more experience with it.

Comment: Write some simple loops with printouts to see what's happening. If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, learn to use the debugger. By using it you can run a program step by step. Its an essential tool.